# search by user.email before get it save cakephp

Tags: cakephp, addition, registering

this is my public add function, but there is a little mistake,

that if the user (his email or username) are exist, this function will save it anyway !

so, how can i do query to search by the [user][email] and then search by the [user][username] to confirm that the username and email which will go to database is a new data with username and email

```
 public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
       ////here it should be the query !
        $this->User->create();
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login' ));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('الموقع مش عارف يسيفك يا فقيع, حاول تاني'));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use the built-in [isUnique](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1166/isUnique) validation rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add validation in your User model

```
public $validate = array(
    'username' => array(
        'emailEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'Sorry, email cannot be empty',
            'last' => true,
        ),
        'email' => array(
            'rule' => array('email'),
            'message' => 'Must be a valid email',
            'last' => true,
        ),
        'emailExists' => array(
            'rule' => 'isUnique',
            'message' => 'Sorry, this email address is already in use',
        ),
    ),

);
```

Comment: except for the order and the missing "last"=>true

Comment: sorry but i have a question !! do any-body, know how to style this kind of error

Comment: read "A few words to validation rules in general" from http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/09/21/saving-model-data-and-security/ - you should use last=>true here since the 2nd and 3rd rules dont make sense if the notEmpty already failed. and therefore it is nice to have the correct orderding (which is not given here).

Comment: ;) now it looks almost perfect. the isUnique should come AFTER the syntax check (since a db lookup is required and is slower than the preg_match)